# Accessing choice parameter values from within Jenkins declarative pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

In my declarative pipeline I have a choice parameter as follows:

```
parameters {
    choice(name: 'sleep_time',
           choices: ['2.5m', '2m', '15s', '50s', '4m', '1m', '1.5m', '1.5s', 'random'],
           description: "the sleep time to execute after the command")
}
```

How can I get all the values of the parameter from within my declarative pipeline?

In this example I am expecting to get the list of `2.5m, 2m, 15s` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During execution the parameter value will hold only the selected choice and not the entire list of options, however because the parameter is defined as part of the pipeline script, you can define the option list as a global parameter for your pipeline and use in in the parameter definition and in any other place in the pipeline.
Something like:

```
// Define the options as a global parameter
SLEEP_OPTIONS = ['2.5m', '2m', '15s', '50s', '4m', '1m', '1.5m', '1.5s', 'random']

pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'sleep_time', 
               choices: SLEEP_OPTIONS, // Use the global parameter
               description: "the sleep time to execute after the command")
    }
    stages {
        stage('Use Global Parameter') {
            steps {
                script {
                    SLEEP_OPTIONS.each {  // SLEEP_OPTIONS is available for all steps in the pipeline
                        println it
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlonTsaraf if this answer solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers